# Create an archive file in bash within debian without installing software

Tags: shell, zip, debian, archive

I want to compress a file in debian 6.0 without installing any extra tools (i.e apt-get zip).

Can anyone tell me if this is possible and if so, what the command is for it within shell / bash.

All the tutorials I have found all tell me to install additional software but I am sure Debian must come bundled with some kind of archiving tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost each new distro has tar included. Use:

```
tar cvzf filea fileb filec
```

This will create tar.gzip archive. If you want it only arch.tar, delete *z* from parameters.

Comment: `tar czvf <out> ...` will create a `.tar.gz` or `.tgz` file, not a `.gzip`.

Comment: `tar` and `gzip` are guaranteed in debian (and derivatives), since apt (currently) uses these internally for the .deb package format. so if your system has a working package manager (which can be expected), you will have both `tar` and `gzip` available.

Comment: A @tar.gz@ or @.tgz@ are, indeed, @.gzip@, the only difference is that the included file is neccesarily a @.tar@, only that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use zip or tar this

```
zip -r filename.zip folderName
tar -czvf filename.tar.gz folderName
```

Comment: He doesn't want to install addition software on his Debian, so zip is not an option.